My Search function isn't working when I search by name
so I've tried creating a Wordpress plugin that searches data in a different MySQL database and it works when I search by license number but when I search for any kind of name I get sent to a "Page not found" page and I can't figure out how to fix it.
Here's the plugin:
    <div class="search">
        <form class="search-form" method="get" action="">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
            <input type="text" name="license_number" placeholder="Enter License Number">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>

        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['name']) || isset($_GET['license_number'])) {
            $name = sanitize_text_field($_GET['name']);
            $license_number = sanitize_text_field($_GET['license_number']);

            

            // Construct the search query
            $conditions = [];
            if (!empty($name)) {
                $conditions[] = $second_db->prepare("name LIKE %s", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($name) . '%');
            }
            
            if (!empty($license_number)) {
                $conditions[] = $second_db->prepare("license_number LIKE %s", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($license_number) . '%');
            }
            if (empty($conditions)) {
                echo '<p>Please enter a search query.</p>';
                return ob_get_clean();
            }
            $where_clause = implode(' OR ', $conditions);

            // Debug: output the constructed query
            error_log("Constructed query: SELECT * FROM licenses WHERE {$where_clause}");

            // Query the second database for license results
            $license_results = $second_db->get_results("SELECT * FROM licenses WHERE {$where_clause}");

            // Debug: output the number of license results found
            error_log("Number of license results: " . count($license_results));

            // If searching by license number, use the name from the license result to search applications and courses
            if (!empty($license_number) && !empty($license_results)) {
                $name = $license_results[0]->name;
            }

            // Query the second database for application and course results using the name
            $application_results = $second_db->get_results($second_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM applications WHERE name LIKE %s", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($name) . '%'));
            $course_results = $second_db->get_results($second_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE name LIKE %s", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($name) . '%'));

            // Debug: output the number of application and course results found
            error_log("Number of application results: " . count($application_results));
            error_log("Number of course results: " . count($course_results));


This is what the results should look like:

This is what I get when I search by any kind of name:

The field in the database is: "name" and the name format in the field is: "LastName, FirstName Middle Initial(if available)" or "Doe, John J".
For the URL with license results, it is: https://domain.tld/plugin/?name=&license_number=12520
Here are some examples of the URL when searching by name: https://domain.tld/plugin/?name=LAST+MICHAEL+R&license_number=
OR https://domain.tld/plugin/?name=bob&license_number=
OR OR https://domain.tld/plugin/?name=bob+lee&license_number=
My error log is inconsistent with updating so that hasn't been helpful.
Thank you for any help!

"name LIKE %s", "%{$name}%" isn't a complete query. You can't prepare that on its own, AFAIK

Anyway, when you submit the form, what URL is it sending data to? That's the source of your problem...presumably the URL is not valid (although your search form has action="" so it should submit to the URL of the current page). But I note this is wordpress and I know it has routing rules and functionality, but I'm not familiar with them. If you provide some sample URL info, then someone who understands Wordpress's scheme better might be able to comment on it. N.B. The code you've posted for processing the search is entirely irrelevant to the 404 error and should't be part of a [mre]

I edited to add the whole plugin code and URL examples.

Pretty sure that's the opposite of a [mre]. Do we need all that code in order to reproduce the problem? Or can it be narrowed down to a more focused set of code? Have you attempted to do that yet?

name is a reserved term, you cant use it, try another variation, example userName
https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms
this case same from this when adding term name in url Wordpress 404 error when adding /?name=someonesname at the end of my URL
